# How can I access variable defined in another method in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: json, parsing, polymer, polymer-1.0, uncaught-exception

I want to access a property, defined in `ready()` of my Polymer element (as seen in the following code):

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-list',

  ready: function() {
    this.tasks = [{
       "task": {
          "name": "OTS",
          "rules": [{"name": "rule 1", "id": "1"}]
       }
    }];

    this.parseJson();
  },

  parseJson: function() {
    this.taskname = JSON.parse(this.tasks.task.name); // errors here
  }
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

for this line:

```
JSON.parse(this.tasks.task.name);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: tasks is an array. use tasks[0]. and tasks is not a json string to parse. Maybe you should learn js properly before using polymer.

Answer (score 2):

`this.tasks` is an array of objects, but `parseJson()` is not using the correct syntax to access array elements.

`parseJson()` should be using `this.tasks[0].task.name`, assuming your actual code can have more than one task and that you're only interested in the first one. Also, you don't need to use `JSON.parse()`, since the task name is not a JSON string.

Here's a working demo:

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-list',

  ready: function() {
    this.tasks = [{
      "task": {
        "name": "Task1",
        "rules": [{
          "name": "rule 1",
          "id": "1",
        }]
      }
    }];

    this.parseJson();
  },

  parseJson: function() {
    this.taskname = this.tasks[0].task.name;
    console.log(this.taskname);
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-list></my-list>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks( Cant upvote as don't have enough credits ). It worked though it threw another error :                                                               VM416:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'O' in JSON at position 0  **as this.tasks[0].task.name returns OTS **

Comment: @Shikha That's because there is no JSON involved here, you don't need to parse your object or string as JSON.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please show you appreciation by accepting it :)